# order topology on singleton set

Tags: general-topology

Let $E$ be a singleton, then obviously there is only one total order on $E.$ Notice that every open interval of $E$ is empty, we can see that the "order topology" of $E$ is $\left\{\emptyset\right\},$ which is not a topology.

**Question:** Should we add the assumption "$\mathrm{Card}(E)>1$" to the definition of order topology?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. The open rays define a **subbase** of the topology, so the whole space is automatically open in the induced topology.

Comment: But the union of all open intervals of $E$  is $\emptyset,$ and if they form a subbasis for some topology on $E,$ then their union should be $E.$

Comment: @painday no, it’s not necessary for a subbase. Munkres is too strict there. If you allow intersections of empty subfamilies $X$ is always in the generated base from any family of sets.  So all families are possible subbases.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: I see, thanks. Some authors cliam that all open intervals form a _base_, which is incorrect. But it's okay if we use open intervals as a _subbase_.

Comment: @painday no, the open segments are the subbase. They’re already essential.

Comment: @painday without the segments ($(a, \rightarrow)$ and $(\leftarrow, a)$) a minimum wouldn't have a real neighbourhood as it is not contained in any open interval.

Comment: @Henno Brandsma: Yes, and when I said "open intervals", I mean the open rays are also included.